# Is there any emperical evidence which (dis)proves the threat of an EMP disabling an electronic safe lock?

Tags: voltage, damage, radiation

The debate between whether to use a [mechanical](http://www.sargentandgreenleaf.com/MN-mechCombo.php) combination lock vs an [electronic](http://www.amsecusa.com/Electronic_Locks/AMSEC_Electonic_Locks/) safe lock seems to be rife with claims with little evidence to back them up.

The pro-combination lock folks are erring on the side of caution to ensure that you have access to your safe contents when you need it the most.

The pro electronic lock folks say worrying about an EMP is moot because:

1. The e-lock is floating and not tied to the grid (they generally run off of two 9V batteries)
2. The actual locking mechanism which stores the combination in a PROM is *behind* the steel plate door of the safe which would act as a Faraday cage. Only the keypad is exposed on the exterior of the safe.
3. The required magnitude of an EMP to take out an e-lock is so large that your body would quickly succumb to the radiation exposure.

So, are the pro e-lock folks right? What *would* it take to take out an e-lock and would I be around to even see it?

Comment: if there is little evidence then it boils down to speculation and who can possibly say what the truth is

Comment: A faraday cage is not some magical device that blocks every and all magnetic fields - it is an attenuator that uses the fact that ferromagnetic materials have a very high magnetic permeability to attenuate a magnetic field. However, these materials have frequency and saturation properties that can certainly be abused to still 'zap' an electronic device behind there. The myth of Ocean's Eleven's truck outside a building generating enough magnetic field strength is of course bullshit, but a small handheld EMP generator next to an E-lock: certainly possible.

Comment: Very little probability of either failing, but they can. In any event the manufacture can gain access using their knowledge of the lock/door construction. A keypad may melt in case of a fire, and fire protection is really what a safe is designed for.

Answer (score 4):

Some [EMP tests](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/108638.pdf) carried out in 1986 suggest that small electronic devices (even sensitive ones) that are not connected to long wires (power, network, large aerials) should survive an EMP.

[image]

This suggests that a battery powered circuit inside a thick steel box would be relatively safe.

Comment: Follow-up question.  Taking into account that electronics have changed considerably in the last 30 years since this test, how relevant are these results today?  Trace lengths have definitely become shorter which would add to the robustness against an EMP but also ESD sensitivity and voltages have dropped considerably which makes me think a latch-up type failure would be easier to obtain. Your thoughts?